# Syntax error on correct usage of else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I keep getting

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax on line 10 (else statement)
```

I've checked my code over and over but I haven't found what's wrong with it. Help me.

```
def phoneCall(min1, min2_10, min11, s):
    minutes = 0 
    costs = [min1, min2_10, min11]
    for i in costs:
        if s > 0:
            if i == min1:
                minutes += 1
            elif i == min2_10:
                minutes += ((s//(min2_10 * 9)) * min2_10
            else:
                minutes += s/min11
    return minutes
```

Answer (score 4):

Your use of the `else` is correct, however you are missing the closing parenthesis (`)`) after you `elif`

You can either remove the opening one

```
minutes += (s//(min2_10 * 9)) * min2_10
```

Or add a closing one

- `minutes += ((s//(min2_10 * 9)) * min2_10)`
- `minutes += ((s//(min2_10 * 9))) * min2_10`